# scala object Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

```
object Util extends Serializable {
    def add(str: String): String = str + " ha ha"
}

object Job  extends Serializable {
    def start(days: Int): Unit = {
        import spark.implicits._
        val data = (0 to days).toList.toDS.map(x => Util.add(x.toString))

        data.collect.foreach(println)
    }
}
Job.start(10)
```

I made a very simple script to test why Task-Not-Serializable issue happens in Zeppelin.
If I change `Util.add(x.toString)` to `x.toString + " ha ha"`, then, totally fine.
But I wonder why I cannot use the object Util here.

Comment: Surprise... I dont have [tag:zeppelin] and i tried this in spark shell it was working fine.... I tested in local test case it was also giving correct result with out appending the string ha ha .. not sure what is going wrong in zeppelin

Comment: can you post complete `Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (` it will clearly indicates what is wrong where is wrong

Comment: It turns out it work on the other spark shell. So, my conclusion is that this is Zeppelin issue. Thank you for checking this @RamGhadiyaram

Answer (score 1):

This was due to Zeppelin. I tested the same thing on the other spark shell and it worked. I hope this case helps the other people's time.